# Excel Formula, Remove Number/First Word After Each Backslash \

Tags: microsoft-excel

I require excel formula to eliminate the numerical value following each backslash \ in order to obtain the desired output as presented below.

D:\Documents\3.0 Mexic\3.1 Vega\3.1.8 O&M\3.1.8.5 ESG\3.1.8.5.3 ESG C\3.1.8.5.3.2 NATUR\3.1.8.5.3.2.2 GUAJI\3.1.8.5.3.2.2.2 01_Pr\3.1.8.5.3.2.2.2.3 Anexo\3.1.8.5.3.2.2.2.3.2 Visit\3.1.8.5.3.2.2.2.3.2.2 P.S\3.1.8.5.3.2.2.2.3.2.2.2 PROGR

output as below

D:\Documents\Mexic\Vega\O&M\ESG\ESG C\NATUR\GUAJI\01_Pr\Anexo\Visit\P.S\PROGR

Comment: This site isn't a script-writing service. You need to show some level of understanding and ask a formed question based on this. Please have a read of https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it with the particular path you gave. It relies on the fact the numbers are always followed by a space. So it will not work if the paths look different.

You can use `TEXTSPLIT` to split the path with the backslash. This will create an array, each element being what's between 2 backslashes.

Then, using the function `LET`, you can test for each element of that array if the first character is a number. If that's true, it returns the `n` rightest characters (`n` being the position of the first space it finds, so just after the 1.2.3...). If the first character isn't a number, it returns the item without modification.

This will truncate all the numbers from the folder names, and your array will only contain what's after those numbers.

Finally, you can reform a path by using `TEXTJOIN`, with `\` as a separator.

```
=LET(x, TEXTSPLIT(E4,"\"), TEXTJOIN("\", TRUE, IF(IFERROR(ISNUMBER(LEFT(x,1)*1),0), RIGHT(x, LEN(x) - FIND(" ", x)), x)))
```

[image]

Comment: A nice elegant solution!